# Apple News app missing

Tags: ios

I have just updated to iOS9 but can't find the Apple News app. All web sites imply that the News app is part of the released version of iOS9. 
Interestingly, the U.K. Apple site [whats new with iOS9](http://www.apple.com/uk/news/) implies its 'coming soon'
Is this a UK only issue?

Comment: Do you still have Newsstand?

Comment: I don't think so ... I never used it, but a spotlight search doesn't list it.

Comment: That's very strange. I'm in the U.S., but have had the News app on my iPad Air since downloading the first public beta of iOS 9.

Comment: "Apple did say it's launching first in the United States, United Kingdom and Australia." From this CNET article: http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/apple-launches-news-app/#

Comment: I have iOS 9.1 beta on my iPad, and it's on that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set your region from settings.app to USA

[image: please see the attachment]

Comment: I set it to Usa on my iPad and it's working since beta 2 even I'm in Turkey and no vpn

Comment: I have changed my 'region' to US, and now it's there!

Comment: “You need to set your region from settings.app to USA” — that’ll make the News app appear, but I doubt this is what we’re meant to do.

Comment: Downvoting because this clearly has an effect on many other things on the system, but the answer doesn't say so. If it's not available yet in the UK, we should say, as describe this as a warning "at your own risk".

Comment: @AndrewFerrier lol that's hardly a reason to downvote people is it? This answer is contributive in its way. You can't just downvote people because you don't agree with the approach personally. At most you shall just add a comment. Also you actually didn't explain what the "effect on many other things in the system" is at all. Shall I also downvote you were it an answer?

Comment: Right, instead on downvoting and griping in the comments, why not just edit the answer to add the relevant warning?